# Powershell reorder an array using prefixes as headers

Tags: arrays, windows, powershell, multidimensional-array

I have the following simple array in a PowerShell variable

Index : 1
Name : Windows 10 Education
Index : 2
Name : Windows 10 Education N
Index : 3
Name : Windows 10 Enterprise
Index : 4
Name : Windows 10 Enterprise N
Index : 5
Name : Windows 10 Pro
Index : 6
Name : Windows 10 Pro N
Index : 7
Name : Windows 10 Pro Education
Index : 8
Name : Windows 10 Pro Education N
Index : 9
Name : Windows 10 Pro for Workstations
Index : 10
Name : Windows 10 Pro N for Workstations

... and I am wanting to reorder it in the example below

Index Name
----- ----  
1       Windows 10 Education
2       Windows 10 Education N
3       Windows 10 Enterprise
4       Windows 10 Enterprise N
5       Windows 10 Pro
6       Windows 10 Pro N
7       Windows 10 Pro Education
8       Windows 10 Pro Education N
9       Windows 10 Pro for Workstations
10      Windows 10 Pro N for Workstations

I have tried using split-string with no luck and I am not sure how to proceed.
Any help would be appreciated

Comment: I think you need to provide more information. Is the array an array of strings with values such as "Index : 1" and "Name : Windows 10 Education". In other words "Index : " and "Name : " are actually part of the value?

Comment: Hey Chad, 
The array is generated by running $imageInfo = Dism /Get-ImageInfo /imagefile:$path, it seems to generate an array of strings. 
I clean up the result by running $imageInfo | Select-String Index, Name. 
When I query the array I get basetype System.Array. The Name and Index are a part of the value and not separate values

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Given that you have an array of strings and not an object it would require some parsing to convert it to a `[pscustomobject]`.

There are many ways of parsing the `array`, here I'm is using [`ConvertFrom-StringData`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/convertfrom-stringdata?view=powershell-7.2) however the same could be accomplished by the use of `split` and `trim`.

Note that, `$imageInfo` is there just to test the code, in your case you should use the variable containing the results from `dism`.

```
$imageInfo = @'
Index : 1
Name : Windows 10 Education
Index : 2
Name : Windows 10 Education N
Index : 3
Name : Windows 10 Enterprise
Index : 4
Name : Windows 10 Enterprise N
Index : 5
Name : Windows 10 Pro
Index : 6
Name : Windows 10 Pro N
Index : 7
Name : Windows 10 Pro Education
Index : 8
Name : Windows 10 Pro Education N
Index : 9
Name : Windows 10 Pro for Workstations
Index : 10
Name : Windows 10 Pro N for Workstations
'@ -split '\r?\n'

for($i = 0; $i -lt $imageInfo.Count; $i += 2)
{
    [pscustomobject]$(
        $imageInfo[$i].Replace(':','='),
        $imageInfo[$i+1].Replace(':','=') |
        Out-String |
        ConvertFrom-StringData
    )
}
```

**Result**

```
Index Name
----- ----
1     Windows 10 Education
2     Windows 10 Education N
3     Windows 10 Enterprise
4     Windows 10 Enterprise N
5     Windows 10 Pro
6     Windows 10 Pro N
7     Windows 10 Pro Education
8     Windows 10 Pro Education N
9     Windows 10 Pro for Workstations
10    Windows 10 Pro N for Workstations
```

Comment: Awesome, you are a legend! I got this to work by converting the line to a string so the replace would work 

for($i = 0; $i -lt $imageArray.Count; $i += 2) {
  [pscustomobject]$(
    $imageArray[$i].ToString().Replace(':','='),
    $imageArray[$i+1].ToString().Replace(':','=') |
    Out-String |
    ConvertFrom-StringData
  )
}